# Pointer to C style string isn't allocated

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *t = "hello world";
   puts(t);
   //printf("%s", t);
   t = "goodbye world";
   puts(t);
}
```

The memory for t isn't allocated, so why I don't get segfault when I run it?

Comment: Can you talk about why you would expect it to segfault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory *is* allocated for `t`; enough memory is allocated for it to hold a pointer (typically, 4 bytes in a 32-bit program, 8 bytes in a 64-bit program).

Further, the initialization for `t` ensures that the pointer points somewhere:

```
char *t = "hello world";
```

String literals are also allocated space, somewhere.  Often, that is in the read-only portion of memory, so you should really be using `const char *t = "hello world";` and even if you don't use the explicit `const`, you should not try to modify the string that `t` points at.  But it is the compiler's problem to ensure that `t` is pointing somewhere valid.

Similarly, after the assignment:

```
t = "goodbye, Cruel World!";
```

the variable is pointing at space allocated by the compiler.  As long as you don't abuse it (and your code doesn't), this is fine.

What would get you into trouble is something like this:

```
char *t;
puts(t);   // t is uninitialized; undefined behaviour
t = 0;     // equivalently, t = NULL;
puts(t);   // t contains the null pointer; undefined behaviour
```

The uninitialized local variable could contain any value; you cannot predict reliably what will happen.  On some machines, it may contain a null pointer and cause a crash, but that is not something you can rely on.

A null pointer doesn't point at anything valid, so dereferencing a null pointer leads to undefined behaviour, and very often that undefined behaviour is a crash.  (Classically, on DEC VAX machines, you got a zero byte at address zero instead of a crash.  That led (in part) to one of [Henry Spencer's](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html) [Ten Commandments](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html) "All the world is not a VAX" — and also "Thou shalt not follow the NULL pointer, for chaos and madness await thee at its end.")

So, in your program, memory is allocated for `t` and `t` is initialized and assigned to point to (read-only) string constants, so there is no excuse for the program to crash.

Answer (score 4):

t is a pointer, so you are just making t point to another string.

Answer (score 4):

Because string literals are allocated statically in your program memory - you do not need to allocate memory for them explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

`t` is here a pointer to the first character of an anonymous string, which can be in read-only memory. A good idea is to declare the pointer as pointer to `const char` :

```
const char *t = "hello world";
```

See also [here](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).

Comment: String literals are often located in a read-only data segment.

Comment: String literals not only have 'static' duration, they are also officially read-only (const).  Therefore, as you said in your answer, @ArashThr, you should not attempt to modify a string literal.  One reason is that it may be in read-only memory and the attempt to modify it will trigger a crash; the other is that if it is in modifiable memory and you modify it, it stays modified for the duration of the program.

Answer (score 2):

All the memory the compiler needs to allocate for `t` is 4 bytes on a 32-bit system. Remember that it's just a pointer. In the first couple of lines it's pointing to "hello world", but after that you change it so it points to "goodbye world". C will have allocated enough memory for the strings you have defined and passes you the pointer so you can point to them. You don't need to worry about that. Also remember that these string are static and read-only, which means you can't safely say `t[4] = 'b';`.